# How to Fill the 'this' Context in Compressor Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, this, file-comparison

I am trying to write a code to compress an image using Compressor library: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor and use this line to do the compression:

```
compressedImageFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(actualImageFile);
```

However, when building my application, I got this error message:

> error: incompatible types: PictureOneFragment cannot be converted to Context

I changed 'this' to getActivity(). I got another error message:

> error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            File imgFile = new  File(pictureFilePath);

            if(imgFile.exists()) {
                File compressedImageFile = new Compressor(getActivity()).compressToFile(imgFile);

                try {

                    mPage.getData().putString(PictureOnePage.PICTURE_NAME + "_" + mPage.getTitle().trim(), pictureFilePath);
                    mPage.notifyDataChanged();

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
                    mImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("eProject : ", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

What is the right context for Compressor library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just little change is there, you have to create **file instance** and **cropImage instance**

in between 
**try{

....
 }
catch(IOException e){ 
...
}**
,because both can throw IOException at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the line:

```
File compressedImageFile = new Compressor(getActivity()).compressToFile(imgFile);
```

And place it in the try block below it.
It's that simple because it can also cause `IOException`.